# How prove this $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{3^k-2^k}<\frac{5}{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

prove that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{k}{3^k-2^k}<\dfrac{5}{3}$$

my idea: use 
$$3^k-2^k>2^k(k\ge 2)$$
then
$$\Longleftrightarrow 1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{k}{3^k-2^k}<1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{k}{2^k}<1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{k}{2^k}=1+\dfrac{3}{2}>\dfrac{5}{3}$$
use this methods,I can't prove it

other idea:
$$3^k-2^k>2\cdot 2^k(k\ge 3)$$

But This same can't prove it
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\dfrac{k}{3^k-2^k}<\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\dfrac{k}{2^k}<\dfrac{2}{3}-\dfrac{2}{5}$$

so This problem have other nice methods? Thank you

Comment: The Maple command $evalf(Sum(k/(3^k-2^k), k = 1 .. infinity),20) $ produces $1.6575611124083585561 $.

Comment: @math110 It seems that you approach is good. Try to split this infinite sum into two parts: the head, which is, for instance, the sum of the first $N$ members (for instance, for $N$=10), and the tail, which is the sum of the rest members. Then calculate the value of the head numerically, and for the upper bound of the value of the tail use the bound $3^k-2^k>\theta^k$ for all $k>N$ and sufficiently large $\theta$. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

By  arithmetic/geometric means, 
$$
3^k-2^k=3^{k-1}+3^{k-2}\cdot 2+\ldots +2^{k-1}< k\cdot 6^{(k-1)/2}.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{k\ge m}\frac{k}{3^k-2^k}<\sum_{k\ge m}\frac{1}{6^{(k-1)/2}}<\frac{1}{6^{(m-1)/2}}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}}
$$
and it remains to choose $m$ as Raymond Manzoni advices.

Answer (score 2):

With your method you would have to compute $11$ terms of the exact sum (for $n>11$) 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{11} \frac k{3^k-2^k} +\sum_{k=12}^n \frac k{2^k}$$
to get something smaller than $\,\frac 53\,$ (for all $\,n>11\,$)

A more accurate variant : $\displaystyle 3^k-2^k>\frac{3^k}2\ $ for $k\ge 2\;$ would still require $6$ terms.

$\displaystyle 3^k-2^k>\frac 45 3^k\ $ for $k\ge 4\;$ seems ok with $3$ terms only.

I'll let you reverify this.